# passing child Type through Lembda in Func<Parent, Parent>

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, func

I have a method defined like this:

```
 public async Task<Parent> UpdateDataAsync(Func<Parent, Parent> updateExisting)
 {
   return await this.UpdateAsync<Parent>(existing => (updateExisting(existing)));
   
 }
```

This can be called like this with Parent's Child class

```
return await this.UpdateDataAsync(
            chld=>
            {
                return chld.UpdateState(State);
            });
```

Compiler complains about not being able to find `UpdateState`.
`UpdateState` is defined on `Child class of Parent`. How can I make `chld` to be passed or inferred as `Child`. I tried to explicitly say `(Child)` infront of `chld` and after the lembda that doesnt work.

Comment: Is this a question - "This can be called like this with Parent's Child class"

Comment: Your question really isn't clear what is the 'Parent's child class' ? what is the relationship between Parent and Child?

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question a couple of times and while its still not clear, I think I get what your asking.

I assume that Child inherits from Parent right?

```
public class Parent
{
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public Child UpdateState(State state)
   {
        //whatever this does
        return this;
   }
}
```

If I'm correct please update your question with this information.

So assuming the above is correct you need to make your UpdateDataAsync method generic with a constraint

```
public async Task<TParent> UpdateDataAsync<TParent>(Func<TParent, TParent> updateExisting)
where TParent : Parent
{
   return await this.UpdateAsync<TParent>(existing => (updateExisting(existing)));   
}
```

This allows C# to know that the item is a Parent while allowing you to work with a subclass

which means you can then do this

```
return await this.UpdateDataAsync<Child>(
    chld=>
    {
        return chld.UpdateState(State);
    });
```

NB the type parameter here is probably unneeded, since the compiler can infer it, but I've included it for clarity